# top-nav covers almost half the screen on mobile

Tags: discussion, top-bar

On a Samsung Galaxy S3 with Samsung's own brower "Internet", I now get:

[image: Horizaontal mode]

Almost half the screen is now covered by the search-box which probably is the nav bar. It used to be fine before.

The new top-bar looks nice on Chrome.

Comment: Use of the desktop website in a mobile browser is not supported.

Comment: It's a non supported browsers so I doubt it will be fixed.

Comment: If you go to the footer, you can click on *mobile* to switch to mobile view. You'll miss a bunch of features but it should be adequate for basic activities on the site.

Comment: For those saying to use the mobile theme, it is important to remember that there are many aspects of the site that are not supported on the mobile theme.

Comment: The site works fine for me on mobile using chrome, firefox, opera, 
 and yandex, It also works for me using the built-in "internet" browser on my samsung galaxy grand prime (2016), which means the one included on your phone is just too old.

Comment: As of rev 2017.2.16.25128 this has been solved! Thank you!